# What's wrong with this ASP.Net Configuration, as it relates to Sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

This probably an obvious solution, but I've been hitting a wall for a while now and just need a second set of eyes to point out what I'm doing wrong.

I've got a new ASP.Net MVC project with the following (relevant) information in web.config :

```
 <system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" name="TestProjectSession" timeout="30" />
   </authentication>
   <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />
 </system.web>
```

All that I'm trying to do (for now, since this broke), is write a value to the session on one page and retrieve it on another...

Relevant code :

Global.asax.cs

`protected void Session_Start()
{ Session.Add("UserID", ""); }`

Authentication Action (after retrieving user info) :

`Session["UserID"] = "useridgoeshere";`

The problem that I'm having is that Session_End is being called when I request any page after the authentication response is sent out. I'm assuming this means that somehow my session configuration isn't valid, but I can't see how based on the information above. Cookies are enabled on the browser, and I've tried using cookieless sessions just in case without any changes.

Can anyone off suggestions as to what I might have configured improperly?

The development environment is VS2010/C#/ASP.Net MVC3

Comment: not directly answering your question, but why are you doing this instead of using a MembershipProvider (ootb or custom)?

Comment: Can you post the code that does the authentication please?

Comment: @Paul - I don't have any sort of roles, nor am I persisting any real details associated with the users other than basic identification/auth information so I didn't want the clutter of dealing with a MembershipProvider .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was related to how I working with DotNetOpenAuth.

I still haven't been able to figure out why Session_End is being called when the authentication response is received (I'm suspecting this may be by design), but I've managed to implement a workaround by persisting the session values I needed (UserID etc) to a cookie and then rebuilding the session from the cookie the next time Session_Start is called.

Answer (score 0):

That all looks fine to me.

Have you got a call to `Session.End()` anywhere in your project? If so, maybe put a break point on it and see if it's being called unexpectedly.

Comment: No, there's no explicit code currently to destroy the sessions.